# Prove if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous and not everywhere zero, then $\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx>0.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Claim:

> If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and not everywhere zero, then $\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx>0.$

I have the following theorem that seems applicable here - more specifically the contrapositive:

> If $g$ is a continuous nonnegative function on $[a,b]$ and if $\int_{a}^bg=0$, then $g=0$ on $[a,b]$.

The contraposition to this statement being (?):

> If $g\not=0$ on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is a nonnegative function on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^bg\not=0$. Where $g\not=0 \Leftrightarrow g>0$, since $g$ is assumed to be nonnegative.

---

I'm not sure if the theorem posted above is at all applicable. However, below are my ideas to proceed.

First note that there exists at least one (?) $x_0\in[a,b]$ s.t. $f(x_0)>0$ or $f(x_0)<0$. I'm inclined to think that there is some neighborhood about $x_0$ so that we can preserve continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Once that neighborhood is established, we may consider cases:

1. If $f(x)>0$, then $f^2(x)>0$, $\forall x\in V_{\varepsilon}(x_0)$
2. If $f(x)<0$, then $f^2(x)>0$, $\forall x\in V_{\varepsilon}(x_0)$

If the above is correct, I'm not sure how to make the jump that in either case $\int_a^bf^2(x)dx>0$ is necessarily true.

This is a homework problem, so I'd prefer just a hint.

Comment: In your second theorem (about $g$), is $g$ assumed continuous?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, Yes $g$ is assumed to be continuous. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Saying that the converse of "$g(x) = 0$ on $[a, b]$" is "$g(x) \neq 0$ on $[a, b]$" might be correct or incorrect, depending on your interpretation of $\neq$. The unambiguous statement is "There is a $c \in [a, b]$ such that $g(c) \neq 0$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: You are on the right track. To move on, denote that neighborhood as $(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)$, such that for all $x$ in this neighborhood, $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < |f(x_0)|/2$ so that $|f(x)| > |f(x_0)|/2$. Then bound the integration by 
$$\int_{x_0 - \varepsilon}^{x_0 + \varepsilon} f^2(x) dx.$$
See what you will get then.

Comment: So my bounds for the integrals should be $\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx>\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\geq\int_{x_0-\varepsilon}^{x_0+ \varepsilon}f(x)dx>\int_{x_0-\varepsilon}^{x_0+\varepsilon}\frac{f(x)}{2}dx>0$
or rather $\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx>\int_{x_0-\varepsilon}^{x_0+\varepsilon}f(x)dx>\int_{x_0- \varepsilon}^{x_0+ \varepsilon}\frac{f(x)}{2}dx>0$?

Comment: Don't forget squaring.

Answer (score 1):

An integrable function doesn't have to be continuous, the theorem you wrote is false (the assumption of continuity is missing or there should be "almost everywhere on $[a,b]$").

---

If a nonnegative continuous function $g$ is not 0 everywhere, then it is positive in some point and - by continuity - positive on some interval $[c,d]\subset[a,b]$. Then $\int_a^b g(x)dx\ge\int_c^df(x)dx>0$.

For any continuous function $f$, the function $g=f^2$ is nonnegative and continuous, so the above theorem works fine.

Comment: I amended the theorem to included continuity, as I forgot to include it earlier.

Comment: ok, now you can use it, in my answer you have a sketch of proof of this theorem

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Here are a few suggestions to keep it going:

1) You have an interval where you can bound your function away from zero.  Can you use the same technique to bound it above some positive number, say $\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$?

2) Once you have such an interval, can you break the integral over $[a, b]$ into three intervals, the middle one of which you have just learned something considerable about?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f^{2}(x) \geq 0$ everywhere. Therefore, if $a \leq c < d \leq b$, i.e. $(c, d)$ is a subinterval of $(a, b)$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{a}^{c} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d}x + \int_{c}^{d} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d}x + \int_{d}^{b} f^{2} (x) \mathrm{d}x \geq \int_{c}^{d} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d} x$. So let $p$ be a point on $(a, b)$ such that $f^{2}(p) = q > 0$, i.e. $p$ is some point where $f^{2}(x)$ is not $0$. Then by the definition of continuity, for $\epsilon = q / 2$ exists some $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - p| < \delta$, then $q - \epsilon < f(x) < q + \epsilon$, which is equivalent to saying that if $p - \delta < x < p + \delta$, then $q / 2 < f(x) < 3q / 2$. Let $c = p - \delta, d = p + \delta$. Then since $f^{2}(x) > q / 2$ on $(c, d)$, it follows that $\int_{c}^{d} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d}x \geq (d - c) (q / 2) = \delta q > 0$. Thus by our earlier observation that $\int_{a}^{b} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d}x \geq \int_{c}^{d} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d}x$, we have that $\int_{a}^{b} f^{2}(x) \mathrm{d}x > 0$.