# Prove that $\int_{a}^{b} f > 0$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am asked to prove that $\int_{a}^{b} f > 0$.

we are given that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
$(\forall x \in [a,b]) \; f(x) \geq 0\; $
and $(\exists x_{0}) \in [a,b] \;s.t.\; f(x_{0}) >0$

my proof goes like so:

In the case where $(\forall x)\;f(x)>0 $ the result is trivial, since $\int_{a}^{b} f$ is bounded below by $(min\, f)(b-a) > 0$

Assume WLOG that there is some point $c \in [a,b]$ such that $c<x_{0}$ and  $f(c)=0$.

Since f is continuous we know by the Intermediate Value Theorem that $\exists \,x_{1}$ between c and $x_{0}$, such that $f(x_{1})>0$. In particular we can find such an $x_{1}$ so that $(\forall x \in [x_{1},x_{0}])\,f(x)>0$

Now define a partition $P$ with points $\left\{ a, x_{1}, x_{0}, b \right\}$.

We want to find the lower sum of $f$ using the partition $P$.

Since we are given that $(\forall x \in [a,b]), \,f(x)\geq 0$, we know that the minimum value the function attains on $[a,b]$ is $\geq 0$.
We also know that on the interval $[x_{1},x_{0}]$ the minimum of $f$ is $> 0$

This implies that $L(P,f)>0$ and since the lower sum is a lower bound for $\int_{a}^{b} f$ we have:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f > 0$$ as required. the same argument can be applied to points $c>x_{0}$.

end proof.

I realise that this is a bit of a mess, so if you have any tips on how to write it more elegantly, I would appreciate them. besides that advice on how to improve the proof from a mathematics point of view is also welcomed.

as always, thanks guys.

Comment: posted recently, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793541/prove-if-fa-b-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-continous-and-not-everywhere-zero-t/1793551#1793551

Answer (score 1):

I propose the academic way:

Due to the continuity of $f$, there exists $\varepsilon$ such that
$
\forall x \in [x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon], \, f(x)>0.
$

Then, $\int_{x_0-\varepsilon}^{x_0+\varepsilon}f(x)dx > 0$.

And

$$
\int_a^bf = \int_a^{x_0-\varepsilon}f(x)dx 
 + \int_{x_0-\varepsilon}^{x_0+\varepsilon}f(x)dx
 + \int_{x_0+\varepsilon}^{b}f(x)dx
$$

The first and third integrals are nonnegative while the second integral is positive.

Comment: this is so much simpler. Thankyou !